# matching group getting added to next group

Tags: regex

I am trying to use this regex

`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\.\d\s([A-Z]{3})((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:(:\d{1,5})?))\s?(.*)`

to match a string such as

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33`

and

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33:2323`

In the case of this string:

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33:2323444 first second`

When I enter a port number with more than 5 digits, the extra digits are automatically included with the next matching group `44 first second` instead of not matching the entire string at all. The port number is meant to be optional (matching it with the IP group if it exists).

The string after the port number is optional as well but, it should be matched when present.

There is usually a space between IP (and port) and the text after, therefore

Standard text should be:

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33`

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33 first second`

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33:23232`

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33:23232 first second`

Example of a string that should not match:

`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33: first second` - If the colon is present but the port is absent or more than 5 digits.

``2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33first second`or`2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33:23232first second`

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/ivR4nd/1)

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a partial match because there is no clear boundary, and using `\s?(.*)` at the end are both optional.

The `.*` can match any character, so the digits after matching `:\d{1,5}` will land in that last group.

Also note that you don't have to escape the colon `\:`

You might use word boundaries and at the end use a negative lookahead to assert not `:` followed by a digit directly to the right `\b(?!:\d)`

```
\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d\s([A-Z]{3})((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(:\d{1,5})?)\b(?!:\d)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wskUae/1).

**EDIT**

After the updated question, you might use:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d\s([A-Z]{3})((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(:\d{1,5})?)(?!\S)(.*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s` Capture group 1
- `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` Capture group 2
- `\.\d\s` Match `.` digit and whitespace char
- `([A-Z]{3})` Capture group 3, match 3 uppercase chars
- `(` Capture group 4

  - `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}` Match an ip like format
  - `(:\d{1,5})?` Optional group 5, match `:` 1-5 digits
- `)(?!\S)` A word boundary, assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `(.*)` Capture group 6, match any characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4emcs7/1)

Comment: The string after the port number is optional as well but, it should be matched when present. This update does not match them in any matching group.

Comment: @hello You can add a group after it matching zero or more characters. https://regex101.com/r/3ZBeIC/1 If there does not have to be a word boundary, you can also use `\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d\s([A-Z]{3})((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(:\d{1,5})?)(?!:?\d)(.*)` see https://regex101.com/r/mHGgCP/1

Comment: Thanks.
The regex matches `2021-05-20 11:03:00.0 GMT222.111.222.33: first second` colon is present but the port number is absent, which shouldn't be.

Comment: @hello I have updated the answer. Did it work out?

Comment: That solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the `(?!:(?!\S))` and `\b(?!:?\d)` are doing? Others I can grasp. Thanks.

Comment: @hello I have updated the pattern to a simpler version and added a breakdown of the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem but this could be the solution:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\.\d\s([A-Z]{3})((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:(:\d{1,})?))\s?(?>.*?)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the fix:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\.\d\s([A-Z]{3})((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}((:\d{1,5})?))$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/oF7HI2/1

Comment: Thank you. Please update to question for a bit clarity.